# Can I use MvvmCross to programmatically bind to indivdual records

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I have an application where I have two vertical Linear Layouts in which I want to place editable rows.  I am trying to use MvvmCross Fluent Binding to bind each record to the proper view.

```
public class SurveyView : MvxActivity
{
    SurveyViewModel vm;
    LinearLayout ItemsView;
    LinearLayout CategoryView;


    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Create your application here
    }

    protected override void OnViewModelSet()
    {
        base.OnViewModelSet();

        this.SetContentView(Resource.Layout.SurveyView);

        vm = (SurveyViewModel)this.ViewModel;

        ItemsView = FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.lvItems);
        CategoryView = FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.lvCategories);

        vm.PropertyChanged += vm_PropertyChanged;

        this.ActionBar.Title = "Survey - " + vm.ShipperName;

        vm.LoadData();
    }

    private void vm_PropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.PropertyName)
        {
            case "Items":
                LoadItems();
                break;
            case "Categories":
                LoadCategories();
                break;
        }
    }

    private void LoadCategories()
    {
        CategoryView.RemoveAllViews();
        foreach (ShipmentSurveyCategory Item in vm.Categories)
        {
            var view = LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.SurveyCategoryItem, null);

            var set = this.CreateBindingSet<View, ShipmentSurveyCategory>();

            TextView tv = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtName);
            set.Bind(tv).For(v => v.Text).To(i => i.Name);

            EditText et = view.FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.txtWeight);
            set.Bind(et).For(v => v.Text).To(i => i.Cubes).WithConversion("FloatToStringConverter");

            set.Apply();
        }
     }
  }
```

I get an error on the 
    var set = this.CreateBindingSet();

Which is 
    Error   CS1929  'SurveyView' does not contain a definition for 'CreateBindingSet' and the best extension method overload 'MvxBindingContextOwnerExtensions.CreateBindingSet(View)' requires a receiver of type 'View'
It doesn't like the "this.".  The ShipmentSurveyCategory object does implement INotifyPropertyChanged.

Can I do what I am trying to do?

Comment: Why are you not using RecyclerView to do this?

Comment: @Cheesebaron The only time I have ever used it was for a Tabbed layout using fragments.  So you can use RecyclerView like a growing rather than scrolling ListView?  You don't by chance have a gist or something I can look at to as an example?  In any case, I will look into it.  Thanks Cheese!

Comment: @Cheesebaron I need to have two lists inside one large ScrollView.  Putting ListViews inside ScrollViews doesn't work.  I can't see where the RecyclerView will allow the two lists to grow as needed.

Comment: It will if you use wrap_content and NestedScrollView and set the appropriate nested scroll behavior on the recyclerview.

Comment: @Cheesebaron I was able to use the MvxRecyclerView with the easy data bindings.  I had to add a CustomLinearLayoutManager which I found in another post.  All together it works like a charm.  Thanks for the pointers bro.  You are awesome!